# Spring data jpa criteria query refactoring

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, specifications, criteria-api

I have piece of code in spring data jpa project which i need to refactor.Actually i want to reduce if else ladder of this method.

```
private static void buildEntitlementFilterQuery(Root<Entitlement> entitlement, CriteriaBuilder cb,
        List<Predicate> predicates, Entry<String, String> entry) {

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(entry.getValue())) {
        if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.START_DATE)) {
            predicates.add(cb.and(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(entitlement.get(entry.getKey()),
                    DateUtil.convertString(entry.getValue()))));
        } else if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.END_DATE)) {
            predicates.add(cb.and(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(entitlement.get(entry.getKey()),
                    DateUtil.convertString(entry.getValue()))));
        } else if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.QNT_GRANTED)) {
            predicates.add(cb.and(cb.greaterThan(entitlement.get(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue())));
        } else if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.VALUE_GRANTED)) {
            predicates.add(cb.and(cb.greaterThan(entitlement.get(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue())));
        } else if (StringUtils.contains(entry.getValue(), Constants.COMMA)) {
            predicates.add(
                    cb.and(entitlement.get(entry.getKey()).in(Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(entry.getValue())))));
        } else {
            predicates.add(cb.and(cb.equal(entitlement.get(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue())));
        }
    }
}
```

Or i have to make each method for each operation ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: It might be useful to add some line breaks in the code sample you provided so that it's easier for others on StackOverflow to read and in turn provide an answer.

Comment: You can also separate out StringUtils.isNotBlank() into a separate line instead of including it in every single one of your conditionals.

Also if the conditions match the case when passed in, this may be a good candidate for a switch